# Spring Data JPA: native summary gets ConverterNotFoundException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

## Update

I've changed the first method to return a `List`, but I get the same exception.

I have 2 native queries in my `Repository` class. One is typed to return all records, the other returns just one row. See below:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = NATIVE_SUMMARY_QUERY_PARTIAL + "group by (rjd.refresh_job_identifier)) as rc")
List<RefreshSummary> getRefreshJobDetailSummary();

@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = NATIVE_SUMMARY_QUERY_PARTIAL + " WHERE rjd.refresh_job_identifier = :refreshJobId" +
        " group by (rjd.refresh_job_identifier)) as rc")
List<RefreshSummary> getRefreshJobDetailSummaryById(@Param("refreshJobId") String refreshJobId);

interface RefreshSummary {
    String getRefreshJobId();
    Date getRefreshJobStart();
    Date getRefreshJobComplete();
    String getUserId();
    long getTotalRecords();
    long getSuccessfulRecords();
    long getPendingRecords();
    long getErrorRecords();
    long getCancelledRecords();
    String getRefreshJobStatus();
}

String NATIVE_SUMMARY_QUERY_PARTIAL = "SELECT  rc.refresh_job_identifier as refresh_job_id, ..."
```

The first method, `getRefreshJobDetailSummary`, works fine. But the second method, where I want only one row, gives me this exception:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.company.repository.RefreshJobDetailRepository$RefreshSummary]
```

The full query looks like this:

```
String NATIVE_SUMMARY_QUERY_PARTIAL = "SELECT  rc.refresh_job_identifier as refresh_job_id, " +
        "rc.refresh_job_start_time as refresh_job_start, " +
        "rc.record_completion_time as refresh_job_complete, " +
        "rc.user_id as user_id, " +
        "rc.pending + rc.successful + rc.cancelled + rc.error as total_records, " +
        "rc.successful as successful_records, " +
        "rc.pending as pending_records, " +
        "rc.error as error_records, " +
        "rc.cancelled as cancelled_records, " +
        "CASE WHEN pending > 0 THEN 'In progress' " +
        "ELSE 'Complete' " +
        "END as refresh_job_status " +
        "FROM " +
        "(SELECT rjd.refresh_job_identifier as refresh_job_identifier, " +
        "MAX(rjd.refresh_job_start_time) as refresh_job_start_time, " +
        "MAX(rjd.record_completion_time) as record_completion_time, " +
        "MAX(rjd.org_usr_nu) as user_id, " +
        "SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(record_status) = 'pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as pending, " +
        "SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(record_status) = 'successful' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as successful, " +
        "SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(record_status) = 'cancelled' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cancelled, " +
        "SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(record_status) = 'error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as error " +
        "from erd_cfg_owner.refresh_job_detail rjd " ;
```

And the value the query returns looks like this:

```
'{20191218204913458hc35, 2019-12-18 20:49:13.314, 2019-12-18 20:49:24.335, hc35, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, Complete}'
```

Can someone shed any light on this? Why would one method work but not the other?

Comment: Could you please provide the complete value of `NATIVE_SUMMARY_QUERY_PARTIAL`?

Comment: @Sternk, sure, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Try to get a String instead of Object at the first. Then you can compare results

Comment: @IharSadounikau, I don't know why I didn't think of that! It absolutely returns a string. I'd prefer the interface, but I don't want the expense of an object mapper. Can you think of anyway to project the interface like I'd really intended? Otherwise, I'll just live with the string...

Comment: Interface as an object, I didn't notice. I suppose hibernate doesn't know the way to map properties. Try with a classic class or abstract class(not sure AC will give a different result)

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the return type of your 2nd method from `RefreshSummary` to `List<RefreshSummary>`. In theory your method is supposed to return a list not a single value

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using constructor expression in query declaration or by creating custom converter.

```
Eg-SELECT NEW com.example.MyClass(e.attribute1, e.attribute2...) FROM MyEntity e");
```

Comment: But RefreshSummary is an interface - I can't use `new`. And I'm not sure how to implement the converter. Can you show me an example?